# Enable zoom of UIScrollView reset zoomed view transformation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, rotation, zooming

First, I would like to precise that it seems there is lot of questions on this subject with no response. The one who gets this answer should be rare.

I set an `UIImageView` as a zoomed view in a `UIScrollView` subclass.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

Just after `self.imageView` creation I apply a CGAffineTransform on it and it's matrix is changed from :

```
(CGAffineTransform) $0 = {
  (CGFloat) a = 1
  (CGFloat) b = 0
  (CGFloat) c = 0
  (CGFloat) d = 1
  (CGFloat) tx = 0
  (CGFloat) ty = 0
}
```

to

```
(CGAffineTransform) $2 = {
  (CGFloat) a = 0
  (CGFloat) b = 1
  (CGFloat) c = -1
  (CGFloat) d = 0
  (CGFloat) tx = 0
  (CGFloat) ty = 0
}
```

After several calls of the `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`  delegate method the transformation matrix of `self.imageView` is changed from :

```
(CGAffineTransform) $6 = {
  (CGFloat) a = 0
  (CGFloat) b = 1
  (CGFloat) c = -1
  (CGFloat) d = 0
  (CGFloat) tx = 0
  (CGFloat) ty = 0
}
```

to

```
(CGAffineTransform) $7 = {
  (CGFloat) a = 0.130719
  (CGFloat) b = 0
  (CGFloat) c = 0
  (CGFloat) d = 0.130719
  (CGFloat) tx = 0
  (CGFloat) ty = 0
}
```

As you can see 0.130 is my zooming scale but my rotation transform disappears.
I'm searching for a way to keep the rotation on self.imageView.

Very Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably sounds a bit Hack'ish but what I would try to do is embed the imageView in a UIView that will be returned by the viewForZoomingInScrollView call.

This way, the imageView will retain it's rotation transform while it's superview will be scaled up or down.

I tend to avoid making assumptions on what does UIKit internally